# NullInjectorError No provider for ElementRef

Tags: angular, typescript

I am receiving this error

```
core.mjs:6362 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(PatientSearchModule)[NgxMaskService -> ElementRef -> ElementRef -> ElementRef -> ElementRef]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
```

here is my module code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { SharedModule } from '../../../shared/shared-module';
import { DemoNgZorroAntdModule } from '../../../ng-zorro-antd.module';
import { PatientSearchComponent } from './patient-search.component';
//import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgxMaskModule } from 'ngx-mask'
  
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PatientSearchComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
    CommonModule,
    DemoNgZorroAntdModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, NgbModule, SharedModule
    ],
  declarations: [
    PatientSearchComponent
    ],
  providers: [PatientSearchComponent],
    exports: [
      RouterModule
    ]
})
export class PatientSearchModule { }
```

Because of it all table data is not showing
[image]

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using? There is a different approach for Angular 16 vs <15

Comment: the angular version is 14.0.6

Comment: If you move `NgxMaskModule.forRoot()` into the `imports` array of your top-level module (e.g. `AppModule`) do you still get the issue?

Comment: yes still getting the issue

Comment: Assuming you are using `ngx-mask@14.3.2` which is the current latest version for Angular 14, it would be great if you could create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in StackBlitz or similar